# Why Does National Data Usually Cite Average Income Rather than Median Income?

Tags: gdp, national-income

When I try to look into standard of living in a given country, I try to find median income figures. I can almost never find them. Instead, all of the data I can find is about average income, GDP per capita, etc. This data is (I think) pretty useless in determining how most people live, because in many of the countries I am looking at, a small number of people receive a disproportionate amount of income.

Is there a reason why median income is not used as the primary figure?

Comment: GDP per capita is easier to calculate (all you need is GDP and population), but I haven't found median income to be difficult to find. For instance, http://news.gallup.com/poll/166211/worldwide-median-household-income-000.aspx